# How to filter a hashmap with specific conditions

Tags: java, filter, stream, hashmap

I have the following initial hashmap:

LatS=[59, 48, 59, 12, 48]

LatD=[41, 42, 46, 42]

EW=[W, W, W, W]

NS=[N, N, N, N]

LonM=[39, 23, 30, 48]

State=[OH, SD, WA, MA]

LatM=[5, 52, 35, 16]

City=[Youngstown, Yankton, Yakima, Worcester]

LonS=[0, 23, 36, 0]

LonD=[80, 97, 120, 71]

I want to filter the Hashmap using the method query that has the following call:

`HashMap<Object, List<Object>> result = df.query( map -> "Youngstown".equals(df.getFrameInfo().get("City").get(0)))`

The definition of the function is:

```
`public HashMap<Object, List<Object>> query(Predicate<Object> cond){

    HashMap<Object, List<Object>> ref = new HashMap<>(frameInfo);

        Map<Object, List<Object>> result = ref.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(cond)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);`
```

But the most dificult part is to obtain the hashmap result in a specific way. I only want the columns of the city passed as a parameter.

For example: if I use this argument:

`HashMap<Object, List<Object>> result = df.query( map -> "Youngstown".equals(df.getFrameInfo().get("City").get(0)))`

the output should be:

```
LatS=[59]
LatD=[41]
EW=[W]
NS=[N]
LonM=[N]
State=[OH]
LatM=[5]
City=[Youngstown]
LonS=[0]
Lond=[80]
```

Thnx you very much!

Comment: It seems that an index of the city has to be defined for the given city name, and then for this index a filtered map should bew returned.

Comment: Is it alright if I make another method that gets the same result?

Comment: I have an answer to this, but like the other answerer, I don't understand your choice of function. Can you explain this further? Also, what is df and the getFrameInfo() method? More information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

First of all, call:

```
df.query(map -> "Youngstown".equals(df.getFrameInfo().get("City").get(0)))
```

does not makes sense really, as in your particular case, provided predicate evaluates always to `true` - which you then pass to the `filter()`.
Note, that you are not using predicate's `map` variable at all.

### Possible solution

I'd suggest to add extra parameter to `query` method, denoting which "key" we are querying (supposing we want to query always single key).

Then, pass predicate for value, which will finds the value for in list for particular "key".

We will get the index for found value, and then construct final `Map` by extracting values for all keys on that index.

```
public Map<Object, List<Object>> query(String keySelector, Predicate<Object> valuePredicate) {
    final List<Object> row = frameInfo.get(keySelector);
    final List<Integer> indices = getColumnIndex(row, valuePredicate);

    return getColumnMap(indices);
}

private List<Integer> getColumnIndex(List<Object> row, Predicate<Object> valuePredicate) {
    return IntStream.range(0, row.size()).filter(columnIndex -> valuePredicate.test(row.get(columnIndex))).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Map<Object, List<Object>> getColumnMap(List<Integer> columnIndices) {
    final Map<Object, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Object, List<Object>> entry : frameInfo.entrySet()) {
        for (int columnIndex : columnIndices) {
            result.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
            result.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue().get(columnIndex));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Example call
final Map<Object, List<Object>> result = df.query("City", "Youngstown"::equals);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Incredible answer hradecek! But then if you want to put an Integer Predicate, what would you have done? Cause when I put:                                                                                               df.query("LatS", entry -> entry instanceof Integer && ((Integer)entry) > 58) it doesn't find nothing. I mean... it goes wrong, and I should to be able to introduce whatever predicate I want.

Comment: I've updated answer so, multiple values can be returned... I've tested your query (copy & paste) on provided data from the question, and the returned result is: `{LatS=[59, 59], LatD=[41, 46], EW=[W, W], NS=[N, N], LonM=[39, 30], State=[OH, WA], LatM=[5, 35], City=[Youngstown, Yakima], LonS=[0, 36], LonD=[80, 120]}`

Comment: Yes I have tested it too! Nice answer, more completely.

Comment: Glad it's working. If it's OK, please upvote and mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: hradecek the last thing. How would you do if you want to put an Integer predicate? I have tried doing:                                                                                                                                          df.query("LatS", entry -> entry instanceof Integer && ((Integer)entry) > 58) but it don't pass the filter and give me an empty map

Comment: `df.query("LatS", entry -> entry instanceof Integer && ((Integer)entry) > 58)` returns: `{LatS=[59, 59], LatD=[41, 46], EW=[W, W], NS=[N, N], LonM=[39, 30], State=[OH, WA], LatM=[5, 35], City=[Youngstown, Yakima], LonS=[0, 36], LonD=[80, 120]}` on your provided test data.

Comment: Well, so strange. In my case return a null map (ArrayList indices=null)

Comment: Are you sure about this answer? I don't get the same output... maybe we can talk in chat?

Comment: Here's the full project I have used: https://github.com/hradecek/stackoverflow-70510939